# Selecionar primeiro nome? - Select no banco

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Estou com uma tabela com os seguintes nomes:

```
João Goldy Alfredo, Gaby, João Antônio, Rodrigo, Maria Aparecida, Mario
```

Como posso fazer para pegar só o primeiro nome deles, e os que não tiverem sobrenome, deve mostrar mesmo assim.

o que tentei:

```
 SELECT SUBSTR(NOMEJOGADOR, 0, INSTR(NOMEJOGADOR, ' ', -3))
FROM JOGADOR;
```

porém com isso consegui apenas pegar o primeiro nome dos que possuem sobrenome, já a Gaby, o Rodrigo e o Mario não aparecem no select. Existe alguma forma de retornar o primeiro nome dos com sobrenome e mostrar os que não possuem sobrenome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você quer mostrar somente o nome de todos os jogadores certo?
Resultando algo assim:

```
João,Gaby,João,Rodrigo,Maria,Mario
```

Se for isso, antes de tudo, precisa padronizar a string, ou seja, temos espaço antes de virgula, virgula depois de espaço.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(nomejogador,', ',','),' ,',',')
```

Depois utilizamos expressão regular para extrair somente os nomes:

```
[[:blank:]][^,]+
```

<sup>(leia-se: Localiza o espaço, encontra tudo que estive entre esses espaço e a primeira virgula que encontrar.)</sup>

Assim temos a consulta:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(nomejogador,', ',','),' ,',',')
                     ,'[[:blank:]][^,]+'
                     ,'')
  FROM jogador
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o NVL

```
SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(NOMEJOGADOR, 0, INSTR(NOMEJOGADOR, ',')-1), NOMEJOGADOR) AS output
  FROM TABELAJOGADOR
```

Se está utilizando Oracle10g+ pode utilizar Regex que é mais simples:

```
SELECT
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NOMEJOGADOR,'(\w+)',1,1) 
FROM TABELAJOGADOR
```

Aqui tem a documentação do [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro teste se existe mais de uma palavra no campo, se existir retorne a primeira, caso nao exista retorne todo o conteudo do campo:

```
    SELECT instr(NOMEJOGADOR, ' ') AS pos_espaco,
           CASE WHEN pos_espaco > 0 THEN
                 substr(NOMEJOGADOR, 0, pos_espaco - 1) 
           ELSE 
                 NOMEJOGADOR
           END AS  primeiro_nome 
     FROM jogador;
```

Answer (score -2):

Assim:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_da_coluna, ' ', 1), ' ', -1)
```

Comment: ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING_INDEX": identificador inválido;

Answer (score -5):

Para pegar o primeiro nome do campo, o comando abaixo funciona muito bem.

SELECT
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NOMEJOGADOR,'(\w+)',1,1)
FROM TABELAJOGADOR

Mas e para pegar o último nome do campo ? Como ficaria a instrução ? Alguém pode me ajudar ?